# How to transmit data from web page to script for writing to db - advice

Tags: php, pdo

I need to write to database from web page somewhere about 80 rows. Table is like

```
CREATE TABLE lan(
id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
fan_coil_id integer NOT NULL,
start_time integer NOT NULL,
end_time integer NOT NULL,
mode integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
day integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

I have script for for writing to db, but I don't know how to transmit those values from my page to script. Do I need with GET request or how ? Can someone give me some advice ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get information from a webpage form to your server -- `GET`, variables appended to the query string of the URL, and `POST`, variables in the body of the HTTP request. These populate `$_GET` and `$_POST` respectively in your PHP code. If you need further explanation, read the PHP manual or buy a book.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the variables through GET or POST and acceess them as array

$_GET['var_name']

Or

$_POST['var_name']

Please read about php/sql security before acting

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` or `$_GET`. See the PHP manual for how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details from your side – yes, you need to get values through HTTP GET or HTTP POST.

Write a form in an HTML file:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="foo"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then access the values through your PHP script:

```
$_POST['foo']
```

Similarly, when you use `method="GET"`, you'd access them in `$_GET`. Read up on writing HTML forms on how to pass the data.